How can i make the intersections library remember the "total" macro outside the specific path?
When defining the intersection coordinates of two paths (via the intersections library), I can store the number of found intersections in a macro for later use, i.e. foreach:
\draw[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[name path=B] (1,0) -- (0,1);

\draw[name intersections={of=A and B, total=\t}] foreach \i in {1,...,\t} {(intersection-\i) circle (0.05)};

However, if I try to use the macro \t outside of this path, it fails:
\draw[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[name path=B] (1,0) -- (0,1);

\path[name intersections={of=A and B, total=\t}];

\foreach \i in {1,...,\t} {
\draw (intersection-\i) circle (0.05);
}

Because the macro \t is unkown. I figured that the defined macro is only available  inside the path which defines it. How can I access it outside or make TeX/TikZ remember the macro for later use?
Full Working Code:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[name path=B] (1,0) -- (0,1);

%%% THIS WORKS
\draw[name intersections={of=A and B, total=\t}] foreach \i in {1,...,\t} {(intersection-\i) circle (0.05)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Code i wish would work, but doesn't:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[name path=B] (1,0) -- (0,1);

%%% THIS DOESN'T WORK :(
\path[name intersections={of=A and B, total=\t}];

\foreach \i in {1,...,\t} {
\draw (intersection-\i) circle (0.05);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I have the same issue with "naming" the intersections with the "name=" option, but that isn't that bothersome. Note that I do have access to the coordinates (intersection-j), but just not the total number. Why are the coordinates remembered, but the macro isn't?

For naming paths, consider using the spath3 library which defines  a key spath/save global=<name> which does what it says and saves the path globally. It is compatible with the intersections library.

@AndrewStacey So does /tikz/name path global.

The coordinates are remembered because all coordinate/node definitions are made global. The total key is not acting globally. But one can make it available for more than that path by doing \tikzset{name intersections={…, total=\t}}. The key does not need to be used on a path at all.

This question is a duplicate of Number of intersection points
Here's a possible solution to the problem for others woth the same problem:
Use the \pgfextra command to define a new macro outside the current path, like this:
\path[name intersections={of=A and B, total=\t}] \pgfextra{\xdef\total{\t}};
% Now we can use \total

Here's a full working example:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[name path=B] (1,0) -- (0,1);

\path[name intersections={of=A and B, total=\t}] \pgfextra{\xdef\total{\t}};

\foreach \i in {1,...,\total} {
\draw (intersection-\i) circle (0.05);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


